# Angular material DatepickerRange get value on change

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have
DatePickerRange of Angular Material and I want to run a function when changing the value in DatePicker I tried with the function (change) but it did not work I would be happy for your help how to do it.
Thank you!

This is my html:

```
<mat-form-field class="form-field">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
        <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date

    </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

And that's the function I want to activate:

```
   @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<bookedDate>();
      addNewDate() {
        this.dateRange.dateStart = this.range.get('start').value;
        this.dateRange.dateEnd = this.range.get('end').value;
        this.newItemEvent.emit(this.dateRange);
      }
```

Answer (score 47):

My approach was to add [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) to the inputs for `matStartDate` and `matEndDate`. These are `dateRangeStart` and `dateRangeEnd` in the template example below:

```
// Template

<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>{{reportField.value.label}}</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="dateRangePicker">
    <input matStartDate
      placeholder="Start date"
      #dateRangeStart>
    <input matEndDate
      placeholder="End date"
      #dateRangeEnd
      (dateChange)="dateRangeChange(dateRangeStart, dateRangeEnd)">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix
    [for]="dateRangePicker">
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #dateRangePicker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The values of these inputs can then be accessed by a function called by the `dateChange` output on `matEndDate`.

```
// Component

dateRangeChange(dateRangeStart: HTMLInputElement, dateRangeEnd: HTMLInputElement) {
  console.log(dateRangeStart.value);
  console.log(dateRangeEnd.value);
}
```

This avoids the need for a `dateChange` event on both inputs.

Comment: It worked the way i want to it to work...Kudos!

Comment: Note that this works only if using the picker. If the value is changes in text, then the function will not be triggered

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem myself, here is the solution that helped me:
component.ts:

```js
    import * as moment from 'moment';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
    import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS,  MatDateFormats } from "@angular/material/core";
    import {  MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
        const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
        parse: {
            dateInput: 'D/MM/YYYY'
        },
        display: {
            dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            monthYearLabel: 'MMMM Y',
            dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
            monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM Y'
        }
    };
    @Component({
        providers: [
            {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS},
            {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter}
        ],
    })
    
        @ViewChild('picker') picker: any;
        dateRange: moment.Moment;
        disabled = false;
        tempDate = new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1);
        range = new FormGroup({
            start: new FormControl(new Date(this.tempDate)),
            end: new FormControl(new Date()),
        });
    
        ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.range.valueChanges.pipe(
                debounceTime(200)
            ).subscribe(event => {
                if (event.start && event.end) {
                    this.onDateChanged(event);
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
  
    <mat-form-field class="date-range" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input
    [formGroup]="range"
    [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: A description to your code would help people understand the solution. Please edit the answer with explanation.

Comment: A debounce is the only seemingly simple way to cause enough of a delay for the calendar  input to reset in the case of when you are selecting an earlier date this is the best solution

Comment: This is incorrect because the end date will be a moment object on the form itself rather than a native JS date(). This you can not override and would have to hack to check if it is moment or native JS date if you wanted to manipulate the values.

Answer (score 2):

i have something similar to your problem it works for me so i hope it can help you or give your a hint about a solution
here is my html :

```
<mat-form-field class="dialogform">
  <mat-label>Duree du Session : </mat-label>
    <input matInput
       required
       placeholder=""
       [satDatepicker]="picker"
       [value]="dateRangeDisp"
       (dateChange)="saveDate($event)"
    >
  <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"></sat-datepicker>
  <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and the function is :

```
     saveDate(event: any) {
    // look at how the date is emitted from save
    console.log(event.target.value.begin);
    //this.session.dateDebut = event.target.value.begin;
    console.log(event.target.value.end);

    // change in view
     this.dateRangeDisp = event.target.value;


    // save date range as string value for sending to db

    // ... save to db
  }
```

Comment: forgot this declaration :          satDatePicker: { begin: Date; end: Date; };
  dateRangeDisp: any;

Comment: Does not work for me, it does not enter my AddNewDate function at all.
thanks anyway.

Comment: it may be basic but press F12 and see what's the error if the there is no one it means it's not even reaching your function and good luck

Comment: I checked clearly ... but I do not see any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Though Matt's answer is a good one, the downside with that approach is that `(dateChange)` fires only on the endDate input change. E.g if user changes startDate by typing, his event won't fire.

I ended up using `Subject`'s to combine the Observables from both inputs. This lets me listen when each individual input was changed. Either by picker, or by typing. By checking `value` carried by the Event we can determine when user has finished picking both valid dates.

```html
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Travel date</mat-label>
            <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
              <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" (dateChange)="startDatePicker.next($event)">
              <input matEndDate placeholder="End date"  (dateChange)="endDatePicker.next($event)">
            </mat-date-range-input>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```js
  startDatePicker = new Subject<MatDatepickerInputEvent<any>>();
  endDatePicker = new Subject<MatDatepickerInputEvent<any>>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const dateChange$ = combineLatest([this.startDatePicker, this.endDatePicker]).pipe(
      map(([a$, b$]) => ({
        start: a$,
        end: b$
      }))
    );

    dateChange$.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data.start.value && data.end.value) {
        console.log('User has picked both ranges!');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `(dateChange)="function()"` to trigger the change in date in mat date picker

Answer (score 0):

@Kirubel and @Irad Amri Thanks!

It works for me in the end this way:

HTML-

```
<mat-form-field class="form-field">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input **(dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" 
(dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"** matStartDate
            formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
        <input **(dateInput)="addNewDate('input', $event)" 
 (dateChange)="addNewDate('change', $event)"** matEndDate
            formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid 
 start date
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end 
 date

    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS-

```
@Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<bookedDate>();

  addNewDate(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.dateRange.dateStart = this.range.get('start').value;
    this.dateRange.dateEnd = this.range.get('end').value;
    this.newItemEvent.emit(this.dateRange);
  }
```

And again, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to subscribe to the formEnd date control with valueChanges and then recover the value of the formStart date control and check if both are not null before lauch any function. So the code may look like:

```
this.dateRange.get('end').valueChanges.subscribe( (endDate: Moment) => {
        
      const startDate = this.range.get('start').value;

      if (startDate && endDate)  { 
          this.doSomething() 
      }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `dateChange` instead

```
<mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker" (dateChange)="addNewDate()">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
```

Comment: As the documentation says, "The (dateInput) event will fire whenever the value changes due to the user typing or selecting a date from the calendar. The (dateChange) event will fire whenever the user finishes typing input (on <input> blur), or when the user chooses a date from the calendar."

Or try  `(dateChange)="addNewDate($event)"`

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example with minimal code?

Comment: This will not work right now as mat-date-range-input has no output events

Comment: As stated in the Documentation `mat-date-range-input` has an output event ```@Output() dateChange: EventEmitter<MatDatepickerInputEvent<D, S>>```. You can refer here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

Comment: @Kirubel nope, it doesn't. the inputs inside it have.